# JFrame: No process

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am learning java GUI with swing library. I know how to make a `JFrame` and add `JButton`, add `ActionListener` e.t.c but today `JFrame` is not showing. I am doing everything as usual. Please have a look at my code and suggest where am I doing wrong..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyGroup extends JFrame {

    private ButtonGroup myGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    public MyGroup(){
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("check1");
        JRadioButton b2 = new JRadioButton("check2");
        JRadioButton b3 = new JRadioButton("check3");
        JRadioButton b4 = new JRadioButton("check4");

        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);

        myGroup.add(b1);
        myGroup.add(b2);
        myGroup.add(b3);
        myGroup.add(b4);

        setVisible(true);

    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ButtonGroup m = new ButtonGroup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `ButtonGroup myGroup` to your frame.

```
//your code
getContentPane().add(myGroup);
setVisible(true);
```

Also in your main method you need to create your JFrame object and not ButtonGroup.

```
MyGroup myFrame = new MyGroup();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new `ButtonGroup` in your main method, not a new `MyGroup`. I would imagine that since the latter executes your constructor and makes your frame visible, that's where your mistake lies!

Comment: `helpAppreciated();`

Thank you for the Answer. I just missed the shot :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You did a simple typo in the main method. Instead of calling the `ButtonGroup` `myGroup`, consider changing it to calling the object `MyGroup` like this:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

       MyGroup group = new MyGroup();

   }
```

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks to you and berry120. You know some times little things make a headache ;)

Comment: Completely understood. Happens to everyone, have a nice day!